Machine learning (GAN) to generate images
I am trying to make the AI I program to generate his own unique images taking as real images a gallery of .jpg images and with the 3 colours channel. But for some reason, it doesn’t look like the discriminator overtrains. I don’t know what I am doing wrong or why is not working.
Code:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torchvision.utils as vutils
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset
from PIL import Image
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Parámetros de configuración
batch_size = 64
image_size = 1025
nz = 100  # Tamaño del vector de entrada al generador
ngf = 64  # Número de características generadas por el generador
ndf = 64  # Número de características generadas por el discriminador
num_epochs = 3500
lr = 0.0002
beta1 = 0.5
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, image_dir, transform=None):
        self.image_dir = image_dir
        self.transform = transform
        self.image_paths = [os.path.join(image_dir, f) for f in os.listdir(image_dir) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(image_dir, f))]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.image_paths)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        img_path = self.image_paths[idx]
        image = Image.open(img_path).convert('RGB')
        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)
        return image

# Transformaciones para las imágenes
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(image_size),
    transforms.CenterCrop(image_size),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
])

# Directorio de las imágenes reales
image_dir = 'Data_Image'

# Crear el dataset y el dataloader
dataset = CustomDataset(image_dir=image_dir, transform=transform)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, nz, ngf, nc):
        super(Generator, self).__init__()
        self.main = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(nz, ngf * 32, 4, 1, 0, bias=False),  # Output: (ngf*32) x 4 x 4
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf * 32),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf * 32, ngf * 16, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),  # Output: (ngf*16) x 8 x 8
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf * 16),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf * 16, ngf * 8, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),  # Output: (ngf*8) x 16 x 16
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf * 8),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf * 8, ngf * 4, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),  # Output: (ngf*4) x 32 x 32
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf * 4),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf * 4, ngf * 2, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),  # Output: (ngf*2) x 64 x 64
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf * 2),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf * 2, ngf, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),  # Output: (ngf) x 128 x 128
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf, ngf // 2, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),  # Output: (ngf//2) x 256 x 256
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf // 2),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf // 2, nc, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),  # Output: (nc) x 512 x 512
            nn.BatchNorm2d(nc),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(nc, nc, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),  # Output: (nc) x 1024 x 1024
            nn.BatchNorm2d(nc),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(nc, nc, 3, 1, 0, bias=False),  # Output: (nc) x 1027 x 1027
            nn.Conv2d(nc, nc, 4, 1, 1, bias=False),  # Output: (nc) x 1025 x 1025
            nn.Tanh()
        )

    def forward(self, input):
        return self.main(input)
    
# Instanciamos el generador
netG = Generator(nz, ngf, 3).to(device)

class Discriminator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, nc, ndf):
        super(Discriminator, self).__init__()
        self.main = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(nc, ndf, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),  # Output: (ndf) x 288 x 288
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(ndf, ndf * 2, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),  # Output: (ndf*2) x 144 x 144
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ndf * 2),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(ndf * 2, ndf * 4, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),  # Output: (ndf*4) x 72 x 72
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ndf * 4),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(ndf * 4, ndf * 8, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),  # Output: (ndf*8) x 36 x 36
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ndf * 8),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(ndf * 8, ndf * 16, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),  # Output: (ndf*16) x 18 x 18
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ndf * 16),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(ndf * 16, ndf * 32, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),  # Output: (ndf*32) x 9 x 9
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ndf * 32),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(ndf * 32, 1, 4, 1, 0, bias=False),  # Output: 1 x 6 x 6
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )

    def forward(self, input):
        return self.main(input)

# Instanciamos el discriminador
netD = Discriminator(3, ndf).to(device)

criterion = nn.BCELoss()
fixed_noise = torch.randn(64, nz, 1, 1, device=device)

# Crear los optimizadores
optimizerD = optim.Adam(netD.parameters(), lr=lr * 0.5, betas=(beta1, 0.999))
optimizerG = optim.Adam(netG.parameters(), lr=lr * 2, betas=(beta1, 0.999))

# Etiquetas de verdad y falsedad con label smoothing
real_label = 0.9
fake_label = 0.1

best_acuariccy = 0  # Variable para almacenar la mejor acuariccy del discriminador

# Lista para guardar el progreso
img_list = []
G_losses = []
D_losses = []

startSaving = 1

# Cargar los modelos guardados si existen
if os.path.exists('discriminator.pth') and os.path.exists('generator.pth'):
    netD.load_state_dict(torch.load('discriminator.pth'))
    netG.load_state_dict(torch.load('generator.pth'))
    startSaving = 0
    print("Modelos cargados exitosamente desde los archivos guardados.")
else:
    print("No se encontraron archivos de modelos guardados. Comenzando desde cero.")

# Crear la figura fuera de la función plot_losses
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 5))

print("Starting Training Loop...")
# Dentro del bucle principal de entrenamiento
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for i, data in enumerate(dataloader, 0):
        ############################
        # (1) Actualizar D con imágenes reales y falsas
        ###########################
        ## Train with real batch
        netD.zero_grad()
        real_cpu = data.to(device)
        b_size = real_cpu.size(0)
        output = netD(real_cpu).view(-1)
        label = torch.full_like(output, real_label, device=device)  # Etiqueta para imágenes reales con label smoothing
        errD_real = criterion(output, label)
        errD_real.backward()
        D_x = output.mean().item()

        ## Train with fake batch
        noise = torch.randn(b_size, nz, 1, 1, device=device)
        fake = netG(noise)
        output = netD(fake.detach()).view(-1)
        label = torch.full_like(output, fake_label, device=device)  # Etiqueta para imágenes falsas con label smoothing
        errD_fake = criterion(output, label)
        errD_fake.backward()
        D_G_z1 = output.mean().item()
        errD = errD_real + errD_fake
        optimizerD.step()

        ############################
        # (2) Actualizar G con imágenes falsas clasificadas por D
        ###########################
        netG.zero_grad()
        output = netD(fake).view(-1)
        label = torch.full_like(output, real_label, device=device)  # Queremos que el generador engañe al discriminador, por lo que las etiquetas son de "1" (con label smoothing)
        errG = criterion(output, label)
        errG.backward()
        D_G_z2 = output.mean().item()
        optimizerG.step()

        # Guardar las pérdidas para visualización
        G_losses.append(errG.item())
        D_losses.append(errD.item())

        # Calcula la acuariccy actual del discriminador
        with torch.no_grad():
            pred_real = (output >= 0.5).float()
            correct_real = (pred_real == 1).float().mean().item()

            noise = torch.randn(b_size, nz, 1, 1, device=device)
            fake = netG(noise)
            output = netD(fake).view(-1)
            pred_fake = (output < 0.5).float()
            correct_fake = (pred_fake == 1).float().mean().item()
        
        current_acuariccy = (correct_real + correct_fake) / 2
        
        print(f'({device}): [{epoch}/{num_epochs}][{i+1}/{len(dataloader)}] '
              f'Loss_D: {errD.item():.4f} Loss_G: {errG.item():.4f} '
              f'D(x): {D_x:.4f} D(G(z)): {D_G_z1:.4f} / {D_G_z2:.4f} acuariccy: {current_acuariccy}')
        
        # Guarda los pesos si la acuariccy actual es mejor que la mejor acuariccy anterior
        if current_acuariccy > best_acuariccy and epoch >= startSaving:
            print(f'El modelo ha mejorado de {best_acuariccy} a {current_acuariccy}.')
            best_acuariccy = current_acuariccy
            # Guardar los pesos del discriminador y del generador en archivos separados
            torch.save(netD.state_dict(), 'best_discriminator.pth')
            torch.save(netG.state_dict(), 'best_generator.pth')
            print('Modelos guardados.')

            with torch.no_grad():
                # Generar una imagen falsa
                fake = netG(torch.randn(1, nz, 1, 1, device=device)).detach().cpu()
                fake_image = np.transpose(fake[0], (1, 2, 0))  # Convertir a la forma (576, 576, 3)
                # Escalar del rango [-1, 1] al rango [0, 1]
                fake_image = (fake_image + 1) / 2
            # Guardar la imagen generada
            vutils.save_image(fake, f'generated_image.png', normalize=True)

        # Guardar las imágenes generadas
        if (i % 10 == 0) or ((epoch == num_epochs-1) and (i == len(dataloader)-1)):
            with torch.no_grad():
                fake = netG(fixed_noise).detach().cpu()
            img_list.append(vutils.make_grid(fake, padding=2, normalize=True))

        # Limpiar los ejes anteriores
        axes[0].cla()
        axes[1].cla()

        # Mostrar la gráfica
        axes[0].plot(D_losses, label='D Loss')
        axes[0].plot(G_losses, label='G Loss')
        axes[0].set_xlabel('Epoch')
        axes[0].set_ylabel('Loss')
        axes[0].set_title('Discriminator and Generator Losses')
        axes[0].legend()
        axes[0].grid(True)

        
        with torch.no_grad():
            # Generar una imagen falsa
            fake = netG(torch.randn(1, nz, 1, 1, device=device)).detach().cpu()
            fake_image = np.transpose(fake[0], (1, 2, 0))  # Convertir a la forma (576, 576, 3)
            # Escalar del rango [-1, 1] al rango [0, 1]
            fake_image = (fake_image + 1) / 2
        
        # Guardar la imagen generada
        if i % 5 == 0:  vutils.save_image(fake, f'result.png', normalize=True)

        axes[1].imshow(fake_image)
        axes[1].set_title('Generated Image')
        axes[1].axis('off')

        # Graficar las pérdidas durante el entrenamiento
        fig.canvas.draw()
        plt.pause(1)  # Pausa para permitir la interacción con la gráfica

        # Guardar los pesos del discriminador y del generador en archivos separados
        torch.save(netD.state_dict(), 'discriminator.pth')
        torch.save(netG.state_dict(), 'generator.pth')
print('Modelos guardados.')

# Graficar las pérdidas durante el entrenamiento
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.title("Losses durante el entrenamiento")
plt.plot(G_losses,label="G")
plt.plot(D_losses,label="D")
plt.xlabel("iteraciones")
plt.ylabel("Loss")
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# Visualizar algunas de las imágenes generadas
real_batch = next(iter(dataloader))
plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.axis("off")
plt.title("Imágenes Reales")
plt.imshow(np.transpose(vutils.make_grid(real_batch.to(device)[:64], padding=5, normalize=True).cpu(),(1,2,0)))

plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.axis("off")
plt.title("Imágenes Falsas Generadas")
plt.imshow(np.transpose(img_list[-1].cpu(),(1,2,0)))
plt.show()

# Generar y guardar cinco imágenes distintas
for i in range(5):
    with torch.no_grad():
        # Generar una imagen falsa
        fake = netG(torch.randn(1, nz, 1, 1, device=device)).detach().cpu()
        fake_image = np.transpose(fake[0], (1, 2, 0))  # Convertir a la forma (576, 576, 3)
        # Escalar del rango [-1, 1] al rango [0, 1]
        fake_image = (fake_image + 1) / 2
    # Guardar la imagen generada
    vutils.save_image(fake, f'generated_image_{i}.png', normalize=True)


I tried making faster the learning process of the generator and slower the learning process of the discriminator. Also, instead of 1 for real images and 0 for fake images I changed so it was less strict and this way the discriminator tends less to get overtrained.
I am expecting that if I give him a library of cat images, he will learn to draw one and the one he drew is not in the library of images I gave him.

What exactly was drawn/outputed?

A completly grey image
